# WordPress: How set all posts in wordpress in one category

Tags: sql, wordpress

I Have 9587 Posts that in 2 category.

I need to delete one category and set it in one category, For-example, I have post in (News, Hot News) categories.

So i need this post in one category (News).

How can do that ??

Comment: So you want to move all the posts in the "Hot News" category to "News"?

Comment: Yes, but for all post have tow category not have one category

Comment: So all categories have the "Hot News" and the "News" category at the moment?

Comment: no some post have another category like ( sport )